# HTML form multiple fields

Tags: php, html, forms

I have html form that looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="?a=up">
...some mysql query...
while ($i = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

<input name="name[]" type="text" value="<?=$i['name'];?>" />
<input name="years[]" type="text" value="<?=abs($age);?>"/>
<input name="to[]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$i['id'];?>" />

}
<input name="" type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

The problem I have is that I can not get the values of the form fields such as "name" and "years". 
I can only get a list of the ids (value of "to" checkbox).

The php code looks like:

```
$cnt = 0;
for($p = 0; $p <= (sizeof($to)-1); $p++)
{
echo $to[$p].$name[$p].$years[$p]"<br>";
$cnt++;
}

$tm = array($cnt);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

## Update

---

Here is how you can get checkboxes that are checked using `isset`:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
  $cnt = 0;
  for($p = 0; $p <= (sizeof($_POST['to'])-1); $p++)
  {
    if (isset($_POST['to'][$p]))
    {
      echo $_POST['to'][$p] . $_POST['name'][$p] . $_POST['years'][$p] . "<br>";
      $cnt++;
    }
  }

  $tm = array($cnt);
}
```

---

You are not getting the fields from `POST` array, here is how your code should be:

```
$cnt = 0;
for($p = 0; $p <= (sizeof($_POST['to'])-1); $p++)
{
  echo $_POST['to'][$p] . $_POST['name'][$p] . $_POST['years'][$p] . "<br>";
  $cnt++;
}

$tm = array($cnt);
```

Make sure that above code executes when form is submitted by putting it in this condition:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
  $cnt = 0;
  for($p = 0; $p <= (sizeof($_POST['to'])-1); $p++)
  {
    echo $_POST['to'][$p] . $_POST['name'][$p] . $_POST['years'][$p] . "<br>";
    $cnt++;
  }

  $tm = array($cnt);
}
```

And finally a little suggestion that you should avoid using short php tags `<?=?>` for they have posed security issues and can easily be embedded into images or xml. (Make sure that they are also turned on from php.ini if you want to use them)

Comment: @Sarfraz - I get the same error. The listed "to" values are correct but all other listed values begin with the value of the first field in the form (that is not checked). I want to get the list of values from the form that have marked checkbox.

Comment: @Sarfraz - This is the result the I get: id-of-selected-field | name-of-field1 | yaers-of-field1

Comment: That is the value which most likely is added to your fields. You can check the source code of the page before submitting the form and see what the `value` attributes contains for these fields.

Comment: @Sarfraz - That was the first thing that I checked. All values in the form are correct. As I said, everything is working fine if I want to get only the list of selected "to" fields. If I try to get the "name" and "years" it doesn't work. I always get the correct TO value and the name and year of the first (not checked) field in form.

Comment: @Sergio: Are short php tags `<?=?>` turned on from php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting a checkbox to be a successful control even if it isn't checked (and the specification says that it must not be so).

You should probably do something along the lines of:

```
<input name="name[<?php echo htmlspecialchars($i['id']); ?>]" 
       value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($i['name']); ?>" />
<input name="years[<?php echo htmlspecialchars($i['id']); ?>]"
       value="<?php echo abs($age);?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just try

```
$cnt = 0;

foreach ( $_POST['to'] as $k => $to ){
    echo $_POST['to'][$k] . $_POST['name'][$k] . $_POST['years'][$k] . "<br />";
    $cnt ++;
}

$tm = array ($cnt);
```

Comment: The problem is that the value of $k in case of "name" and "years" always begin with the zero, not with the selected value. As result of that I always get the value of the first field, but not of the selected one.